# How to add specific android platform to ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

I am creating ionic project and adding platform for android using 'ionic platform add android' command. Added platform is targeting only to android platform-22.
but i want to add android platform-19. (that option is available in android studio). How to add specific android platform in ionic

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionic platform add android@4.4.2`. In case of platforms you can install version using notation: `ionic platform add platformName@version`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update Android SDK platform.

Go to android-sdk installed folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) you could find Android SDK Manager there. Click on it. After opened it, you could update your Android SDK platforms as you did it in android studio.

[image]